# Quartz job error in production with grails 2.3.7

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

With quartz scheduler plugin (v1.0.1) for grails and using the same piece of code to execute a quartz job:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger

import org.quartz.DisallowConcurrentExecution
import org.quartz.Job
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException
import org.quartz.PersistJobDataAfterExecution


@PersistJobDataAfterExecution
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
class AccountingWatchJob implements Job {

    def sessionRequired = false
    def concurrent = false
    def volatility = false
    def group = "AccountingProcess"
    def accountingWatchService

    static triggers = {
        // daily at 5:00 am
        cron name:'triggerPayment', startDelay:300000, cronExpression: '0 0 5 * * ?'

    }

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {

        try {
            accountingWatchService.start()
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            log.error(e)
        }


    }
}
```

It gives an error in production mode only =>

```
[quartzScheduler_Worker-1] ERROR grails.app.jobs.com.ubiness.ubistore.AccountingWatchJob  - java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
```

Comment: Is that really all you get for error output?

Comment: i'm unable to reproduce in dev mode. I've as well tried to deploy a dev war on a local tomcat instance 7.0.52 but the exception is raised on EBS tomcat instance (7.0.47)..